# change desktop environment

Tags: desktop-environments, display-manager

How I can change my desktop environment after logoff, I cannot choose more than 10 desktop environments? Numbers bigger than 10 are not displayed.

Old problem. I tried other display-managers but it is that same - does not slide on the list.

[image]

Comment: what window managers are you missing ? See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89268/how-do-i-edit-the-list-of-window-managers-that-appear-in-gnome-login

Answer (score 0):

I checked a few other display managers:

1. This is not working - undisplay part of the list of desktop session.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xymx8.jpg
2. This is working (Slim Display Manager), but it's necessary to click F1 to change session.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeigP.jpg
3. LXDM - LX Display Manager is showing a full list of desktop sessions.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkaVo.jpg